# div not centering if table is too wide

Tags: html

My page has a main div which centers the page.
I do this by using margin: auto;

The page itself works nicely - but once I include a table which loads data dynamically from a database, the page does not align to the initial center properly.

Please see the example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Invoice Control</title>
</head>

<body class="single">

<div id="wrapper" style="width:1100px;margin:auto;padding:10px; border: 1px solid gray">

    <div id="content" style="border: 1px solid red">

        here comes the table, which makes the site not center nicely

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
                <td>THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

any idea what I have to do, to make sure that the centered div centers again properly?

Comment: you have large no if TD so i thinks it will not center the page, you can use overflow property on DIV

Comment: You can try this `<div id="content" style="border: 1px solid red; overflow: auto;">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the overflowing of your div. As your demonstration shows you have the box that is sized to 1100 pixels correctly centering but your table is coming out of it. The reason is that the table cannot be made any smaller due to words that cannot be split forcing a minimum width for columns and thus for the table as a whole.

There are a few options to solve this depending on what you want to do. The best in my view would be to change the `width: 1100px;` to `min-width:1100px`. This will allow the div to expand if its contents want to be larger than 1100px as in this case.

Alternatively you could use the overflow style on the div to create scrollbars or hide the overflow.

Comment: thank you for the hint! It makes the table "grow" correctly. However, it doesn't squeeze the table together. If you check my example the dummy text is squeezed to a maximum and you only get 1 word per line. If I use the min-width even if I have less columns the table won't squeeze to the minimum but have more words next to each other. Your solution works and answers the question though - thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your responses.

They pointed me into the right direction, even though I have decided to go with another solution.

What I don't like about the "min-width" is the fact that the table always scales to 100%. In my example the text "THIS IS DUMMY TEXT TO FILL THE TABLE AND EXCEED THE 1100PX" is not squeezed together at a maximum, but takes all available space on the site. 
This sounds fine, but actually doesn't really fit to the rest of my page (e.g background image).
The "extra wide" table is an exception in my context, and I would like to make sure that the table is squeezed together as a maximum and the site "grows" as little as possible.

I have therefore used some java script to help me.
I find out the width of the table

```
if ($(".myTable").width() > 1100px) {
      $(".myTable").width($(".myTable").width() + 5);
}
```

knowing that this is probably not the most beautiful solution it feeds the purpose.
Or do you have any Idea which CSS styles I could apply to the table to make sure it always scales to a minimum if it exceeds the 1100px from the "centered div"?